# Efficiently save indices of nonzero matrix elements to a file

Tags: r, performance, matrix, file-writing

I need to save the indices of a matrix's nonzero elements to a file. This works very well for small-sized matrices, storing the row numbers of the non-zero indices in `a` and the column numbers of the non-zero indices in `b`:

```
X <- matrix(c(1,0,3,4,0,5), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2);    
a <- row(X)[which(!X == 0)]
b <- col(X)[which(!X == 0)]
```

But size of the matrix is huge, and I need to find an efficient way to save the indices to a txt file, so that I have a[1] b[1] (new line) a[2] b[2] and so on. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `Matrix` has a great solution for extremely large matrices. The `sparseMatrix` object can be summarized into a data.frame where `i` and `j` are your indices and `x` is the value:

```
X <- matrix(c(1,0,3,4,0,5), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2);    
a <- row(X)[which(!X == 0)]
b <- col(X)[which(!X == 0)]

library(Matrix)
Y <- Matrix(X, sparse = TRUE)
(res <- summary(Y))
  2 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix", with 4 entries 
    i j x
  1 1 1 1
  2 2 1 4
  3 1 3 3
  4 2 3 5
class(res)
  [1] "sparseSummary" "data.frame"
```

You can then subset to get just `i` and `j`:

```
res[, c("i", "j")] 
   i j
 1 1 1
 2 2 1
 3 1 3
 4 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the rows and columns of all non-zero locations using `which` with parameter `arr.ind=TRUE`, writing the result to a file with `write.table`:

```
write.table(which(X != 0, arr.ind=TRUE), "file.txt", row.names=F, col.names=F)
```

This yields space-separated output of the pairs of elements in the specified file:

```
1 1
2 1
1 3
2 3
```

Using `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` saves a few scans through your input matrix compared to the code posted in your question, so it should be a bit quicker at calculating the data to output. You can see this with a benchmark for a larger matrix (1000 x 1000, with 1% density):

```
set.seed(144)
bigX <- matrix(sample(c(rep(0, 99), 1), 1000000, replace=T), nrow=1000)
OP <- function(X) cbind(row(X)[which(!X == 0)], col(X)[which(!X == 0)])
josilber <- function(X) which(X != 0, arr.ind=TRUE)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OP(bigX), josilber(bigX))
# Unit: milliseconds
#            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#        OP(bigX) 20.513535 23.014517 36.463423 25.354250 59.130520 65.50304   100
#  josilber(bigX)  3.873165  4.281624  6.741824  5.250777  6.998415 45.02542   100
```

In this case we see about a 5x speedup in computing the non-zero rows and columns. Depending on the density and size of your matrix the output operation (`write.table`) might instead be the bottleneck, in which case there may not be too much benefit to this approach.